# Keyboard height giving 0 on first load - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am trying to move the view up when the keyboard appears, using the following code:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
if let keyboardSize: CGSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size {

            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
                print("Keyboard height is: \(keyboardSize.height)")

                let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height - (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)!
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= (keyboardHeight)
                print("Keyboard height is: \(keyboardSize.height)")

        }
    }
}
```

The first time this function is called once the app has been opened, keyboard height is populated as 0, meaning the view drops by the height of the tabBar. When I reload the view, it works perfectly from then on.

It seems like I am not getting the keyboard height until the keyboard is actually opened, which is too late for the first run of the function.

Any idea what the issue is? Please let me know if you want any more details.

Answer (score 9):

Use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I tried that too but doesnt seem to make a difference. This is happening within a TabViewController if you think that would make a difference?

Comment: Worked for me
Thanks...!!

Answer (score 1):

> For swift 3.0 and above

```
@objc private func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification){
if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
{
  print("keyboardSize.height = ",keyboardSize.height)
}  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this

first

```
var iskeyboard : Bool = false;
```

for show

```
  func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        if (!iskeyboard)
        {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
        iskeyboard = true

    }
}
```

for hide

```
  func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        if (iskeyboard)
        {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
         iskeyboard = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but the same thing is still happening with your code. I couldn't find any info about it anywhere else on Stackoverflow either...very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to access keyboardHeight before the keyboard is shown.

Listen to keyboardDidShow(*:) instead of keyboardWillShow(*:) and you'll get the correct keyboard height.

use this instead:

```
func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
if let keyboardSize: CGSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size {
       //DO YOUR STUFF
} }
```